# Prevent a GNU Screen session from closing

Tags: gnu-screen

So I run `Irssi` on my VPS inside a GNU Screen session and sometimes accidentally close `Irssi` process when I log out, therefore forgetting to close the Screen session beforehand. Is there a way that I can prevent a Screen session from closing on disconnect?

Comment: So... your question is more about GNU Screen than Irssi?

Comment: Yes, my question is primarily about Screen. If you have an alternate solution to keep Irssi always open, I am all ears.

Comment: You may have some luck with one of these: [Using GNU Screen completely transparently and automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075947/using-gnu-screen-completely-transparently-and-automatically) [Automatically (or more easily) reconnect to a screen session after network interruption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474967/automatically-or-more-easily-reconnect-to-a-screen-session-after-network-inter)